# csvtojson printing unknown charcters

Tags: javascript, node.js, csvtojson

I am trying to convert csv to json. This CSV contains emojis,  i guess that might be the problem.

csvtojson or any other module or even any custom method is returning unknown characters/garbage characters.
My csv file link below:

[CSV](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tbACRUcuxP5aeauRD4TFfUwaO61L0_6i/view?usp=sharing)

The code i am using is:

```
let csvFilePath = path.join(\__dirname, 'reports/xyz.csv');

let str1 = fs.readFileSync(csvFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' }).toString();

csv({noheader:true,output: "csv"}).fromString(str1).then((csvRow)=\>{console.log(csvRow)});
```

It is returning a bunch of \x00c\x00o\x00m\x00.\x00b\x00h\x00a\x00k\x00t\x00 characters.

Comment: Why are you reading the file first into a string, instead of using [`csv.fromFile()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#from-csv-file-to-json-array)?

Comment: I have also used csv.fromFile() that is resulting in same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to print your csv file in console and it indeed shows unicode character identifier.

The problem is not with `csvtojson` module rather with the csv.

I have opened webstorm debugger while running your code. This is the first line of your csv as json object. See the vertical lines between each character both in every key and value of the row object. This is a problem with the format of the csv and the software used to write it. The csv you provided has invisible characters. I don't actually know why this would be present in all of the characters but it does exist in the file.

[image: Webstorm debugger screenshot]

Now for your options:

1. You can sanitize the csv first. Get rid of this invisible character and then print/parse,
2. Regenerate the csv if it was autogenerated. If not, try copy pasting to another csv by copying the tabular data from the google spreadsheet app. I don't know if this will work in this case. Be sure to paste value only, not formatting which might be helpful.

Comment: How can i sanitize the csv? Is there any module for that? I need to do every on code. I am getting this csv from google cloud storage.

Comment: I am sorry. I can't paste the code here. 
Stackoverflow won't let me paste the "unsafe" characters I think.

Comment: I have used https://pastebin.mozilla.org/1zFpcJAn to store the code for now. It will expire soon. Test it and let me know.

Comment: Looks like it is expired. Can you republish it?